# Stimulate SendKey inputs within an application?

Tags: c#, winforms, sendkeys

I am trying to create a function to stimulate some simple user input like enter in my application. 
The function is actually running behind a backgroundworker while an update process was running.
However, when I minimize the application and went to the browser doing some search for instance, the sendkey "enter" will perform enter on the search bar instead.

My question is how can I perform the key down stimulation within an application only and not outside of it?

Below is some snippet.

```
foreach (TextBox tb in this.panel2.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
  if (tb.ReadOnly == false)
  {
     tb.Focus();
     SendKeys.SendWait("{Enter}");
  }                 
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to keep sending the key while the application is in focus?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for reply. Yes, I want to keep sending key while the application is in focus and prevent the key sent when I leave the application. how can I achieve this?

Comment: And this is why you should never use SendKeys.  There's just no point when you can use tb.AppendText().

Answer (score 1):

You can use the static property `Form.ActiveForm` to know if your application `temporarily goes away from screen` or your form is not active to handle the `SendKey` correctly:

```
Control lastControl;
public void StartSendingKey(){
  foreach (TextBox tb in this.panel2.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()) {
    if(lastControl != null && tb != lastControl) continue;//Skip the textBoxes receiving SendKeys
    if(Form.ActiveForm == null) {
       lastControl = tb;
       return;//check if your application is not active then exit method
    }
    //if(Form.ActiveForm != yourForm) return;//check if your form is not active then exit method
    if (!tb.ReadOnly) {
      tb.Focus();
      SendKeys.SendWait("{Enter}");
    }                 
  } 
  lastControl = null;//Set this if you want SendKeys many times repeatedly.
}
//Activated event handler for your Form1
private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e){
   StartSendingKey();
}
```

Comment: That lowers the odds for a mishap, it doesn't make them zero.

Comment: Hi..thanks for reply..the codes you provided seems working but what I actually want is hold it on when the form is not active and resume when the form actives back, not break it.

Comment: @Therenho I don't get your idea well. When is your foreach loop executed? How many times should it be executed?

Comment: 1 time per textbox. My idea is quite straight forward. Focus the textbox and stimulate the enter key. When the form inactive, the enter key will hold on the key and resume when the form becomes active. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: @Therenho see my update if it helps you now, although I don't still really understand why you want such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

I used this

```
    Timer tmr = new Timer();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(tmr_Tick);
    }

    void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ActiveForm == this)
            SendKeys.Send("{A}");
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tmr.Start();
    }
```